# Continuous audio for Flash CS5 (Actionscript 2.0)

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I made a menu which has multiple SWF files. In the first movie, the audio is playing but in the second SWF, my audio is not playing.

Is there any way to use only one audio for multiple SWF files without putting the audio on every each one of them?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility of doing that if the sound and the other 
swf files are in the same directory
and load THAT audio to the swf.

```
var s:Sound = new Sound();

s.onLoad = function():Void
{
    trace("Song loaded.");
};

s.onSoundComplete = function():Void
{
    trace("Song done.");
};

s.loadSound("music.mp3", true);
```